# How to resume reading a file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to find the best and most efficient way to resume reading a file from a given point.

The given file is being written frequently  (this is a log file). 
This file is rotated on a daily basis.

In the log file I'm looking for a pattern 'slow transaction'. End of such lines have a number into parentheses. I want to have the sum of the numbers.

Example of log line:

Jun 24 2015 10:00:00 slow transaction (5)

Jun 24 2015 10:00:06 slow transaction (1)

This is easy part that I could do with awk command to get total of 6 with above example.

Now my challenge is that I want to get the values from this file on a regular basis. I've an external system that polls a custom OID using SNMP. When hitting this OID the Linux host runs a couple of basic  commands.

I want this SNMP polling event to get the number of events since the last polling only. I don't want to have the total every time, just the total of the newly added lines.

Just to mention that only bash can be used, or basic commands such as awk sed tail etc. No perl or advanced programming language.

I hope my description will be clear enough. Apologizes if this is duplicate. I did some researches before posting but did not find something that precisely correspond to my need.

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: Can renaming the file using `mv filename newfilename` to "reset" the file  fit your use case?

Comment: See [**how to write a script that only acts on new log entries**](http://serverfault.com/questions/355311/how-to-write-a-script-that-only-acts-on-new-log-entries)

Comment: wc to get num lines in the file. Then save this, then use `wc -l` again and subtract the previous. Then use tail and that many lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answers already. I'm certain there are dozen of manners to do that. I have some ideas in mind too like the wc -l + subtract. What I'm looking for is a sexy and efficient way to do that. If possible with limited footprint on the system (no file copy since the log file is big for ex).

Comment: I believe the [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) utility could help.

Comment: @User112638726 : good one but I also had in mind writing some kind of  check point into a temp file and then resume next processing from that  check point.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the methods in the comment link, you can also simply use `dd` and `stat` to read the logfile size, save it and `sleep 300` then check the logfile size again. If the filesize has changed, then skip over the old information with `dd` and read the new information only.

**Note:** you can add a test to handle the case where the logfile is deleted and then restarted with `0` size (e.g. `if $((newsize < size))` then read all.

Here is a short example with `5 minute` intervals:

```
#!/bin/bash

lfn=${1:-/path/to/logfile}

size=$(stat -c "%s" "$lfn")         ## save original log size

while :; do

    newsize=$(stat -c "%s" "$lfn")  ## get new log size
    if ((size != newsize)); then    ## if change, use new info

        ## use dd to skip over existing text to new text
        newtext=$(dd if="$lfn" bs="$size" skip=1 2>/dev/null)

        ## process newtext however you need
        printf "\nnewtext:\n\n%s\n" "$newtext"

        size=$((newsize));          ## update size to newsize
    fi
    sleep 300

done
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the suggestion. Appreciated. I was not clear enough in my original post: in fact every 5 minutes I've an external monitoring tool that will perform SNMP polling automatically. On my Linux host I define a custom OID (the one the monitoring tool is polling). When the custom OID is being polled then I execute some commands to return a value from my log file. But I don't want to return the value from the begging of the log file everyone, only the added value since the last polling.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The good news is the same approach will work. When you execute the commands to return the value from the log file, as long as they can check the new `stat -c "%s" "$logfile"` against the value of `stat -c "%s" "$logfile"` from the last call (you can save the value in a temp file) you can then provide only the new info from the log with `dd if="$logfile" bs="$oldsize" skip=1 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks David. Don't be sorry my initial description wasn't that clear... I just put more details to clarify. Also I'm gonna test your suggestion on Monday and let you know.

Comment: You know, the more I think about your situation, the more using a `FIFO` makes the most sense. In the link I provided in my first comment to your question, there is an example using a `FIFO`. You will simply redirect your logfile to the `FIFO`, then when your OID is polled and you execute your commands, the only data available in the FIFO will be the new logfile entries.

Comment: like that! Let me give it a try.

Comment: The main issue I see with using a FIFO is the potential to overflow the FIFO.  It depends on how you do it.  The main log must continue to be separate.  It would be feasible, perhaps, to run `tail -f logfile | grep 'slow transaction' > FIFO` and then monitor the FIFO without too much difficulty.  Sometimes, this could block because there isn't enough space in the pipe and FIFO, but it doesn't matter too much.  The biggest problem is detecting when the log file is no longer being written to.

Comment: Hum.. I'll pay attention to that. My first FIFO will then not be an easy one 